# Media queries in e-mails?

Tags: html, email, media-queries

made my very first responsive one column email today. Happens to work on all clients, I was very proud of myself. Until my boss wanted me to make it so that it displayed a different version on desktops and then a different version for mobiles. This can probably best be described as responsive, though the header would be a full width 1000px header and then when it gets to a certain px (probs 600px) it would display: none and then a media query kicks in to display a certain class that replaces that header.

Hope i am being clear here, i have a tendency to overcomplicate things....

here is a link to my site for where the source for the html email is living : http://www.muhammadkasimali.co.uk/ZurbFoundation/

BTW i did not use the zurb framework (despite the directory name), it was a giant waste of time pursuing that route imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include media queries in emails **but** you need to be aware of what device email client will support it. This [link here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/) should help in explaining email responsivity and gives you a good amount of detail.